# Directory turns into file after ant build. How to handle that?

Tags: java, ant, antbuilder

The method below is supposed to read classes/files out of a certain directory. It works alright when debugging the method in eclipse. But after building it using ant the scannedDir is not a directory anymore. Does anyone know how to change it so that it still works after deployment? Thanks in advance!

```
private static List<Class<?>> find(String scannedPackage) {

    logger.trace("Scanned package='{}'", scannedPackage);
    String scannedPath = scannedPackage.replace(DOT, SLASH);
    logger.trace("Scanned path='{}'", scannedPath);
    URL scannedUrl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(scannedPath);
    logger.trace("Scanned url='{}'", scannedUrl);

    if (scannedUrl == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(BAD_PACKAGE_ERROR, scannedPath, scannedPackage));
    }

    File scannedDir = new File(scannedUrl.getFile());
    logger.trace("scannedDir.isDirecory='{}'", scannedDir.isDirectory());
    List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();

    for (File file : scannedDir.listFiles()) {
        logger.trace("currentFile='{}'", file.getAbsolutePath());
        classes.addAll(find(file, scannedPackage));
    }

    return classes;
}
```

So in detail: When I run it using eclipse debug mode `scannedDir.isDirectory=true`. But after building it `scannedDir.isDirectory=false`

Cheers!

EDIT:

`scannedDir.getAbsolutePath()` returns `jar:file:/C:/Users/xxx.xxx/AppData/Local/XBRLGEN/app/xbrl_s2.jar!/eu/europa/eiopa/xbrl/s2c/dict/dom`

Comment: Did you print out the `URL`? If you have built a `jar` file, the `URL` will not have a `file:` protocol and can’t be converted to a `File` object.

Comment: Its a jar file! Added the output to my post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t treat entries in a jar file like `File`s, that will never work. You are also misinterpreting the problem. Just because the `File` says that it isn’t a directory doesn’t imply that it is an ordinary file, it simply doesn’t exist as you have extracted a part of a `jar:` URL and interpreted as an ordinary file.

Here is a solution of your task working on an abstraction that doesn’t require ordinary files:

```
private static Set<Class<?>> getClasses(String pkg)
  throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    ClassLoader cll = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

    URI clURI = cll.getResource(pkg.replace('.', '/')).toURI();
    if(!clURI.getScheme().equals("file")) try {
        FileSystems.getFileSystem(clURI);
    } catch(FileSystemNotFoundException ex) {
        FileSystems.newFileSystem(clURI, Collections.emptyMap());
    }
    return Files.list(Paths.get(clURI))
        .map(p->p.getFileName().toString())
        .filter(s->s.endsWith(".class"))
        .map(s->s.substring(0, s.length()-6))
        .map(s-> { try {
            return cll.loadClass(pkg+'.'+s);
          } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) { return null; } })
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

but it is unreliable as `jar` files are not required to have entries for directories at all. In the case of absent entries, directories exist only implied due to the fact that an entry of a regular file inside that directory exist, e.g. an entry `foo/bar` implies that there is a directory `foo`. In this case, `getResource` attempts for the directory will fail.

The safest way to query a package is to pick one class inside that package and perform a lookup on it as the associated resource definitely exist. Then you can traverse the parent of it, even if its existence is only implied:

```
private static Set<Class<?>> getClasses(Class<?> context)
    throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    ClassLoader cll = context.getClassLoader();

    URI clURI = context.getResource(context.getSimpleName()+".class").toURI();
    if(!clURI.getScheme().equals("file")) try {
        FileSystems.getFileSystem(clURI);
    } catch(FileSystemNotFoundException ex) {
        FileSystems.newFileSystem(clURI, Collections.emptyMap());
    }
    String pkg=context.getPackage().getName();
    return Files.list(Paths.get(clURI).getParent())
        .map(p->p.getFileName().toString())
        .filter(s->s.endsWith(".class"))
        .map(s->s.substring(0, s.length()-6))
        .map(s-> { try {
            return Class.forName(pkg+'.'+s, false, cll);
          } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) { return null; } })
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It basically works! I only have to change it so that it crawls recursively through subfolders.